# -bash: grunt: command not found - mac OSx

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, gruntjs, homebrew

I'm a bit of a newbie. 
Here is the information I can provide and I can provide further information is needed. I've documented everything i've done. 
 I'm a quick learner too.

I'm on MAC OSX El Capitan

I was using this tutorial as my guide (possibly why I might be running into problems)
https://changelog.com/posts/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x

I've even installed grunt

```
sudo npm install grunt -g
```

It even gives me this path

```
/Users/<file path>/.node/bin/grunt -> /Users/<file path>/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt
```

I also know that this is related to my `$PATH`

```
PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin:$PATH
```

It looks like everything is installing properly.

When I run:

```
grunt
```

I get:

> -bash: grunt: command not found

If i type:

```
grunt -v
```

I get:

> bash: grunt: command not found

I've even been over here to troubleshoot and nothing seems to work.
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

I've looked at so many issues related on stackoverflow but nothing that seems to work for my problem.

Is there a way of doing a fresh install of everything and clearing my computer of everything related.

I would also love to have an example of something that works properly on my computer for a newbie to learn. Maybe I shouldn't of use homebrew to set it up.

Much help appreciated.

Comment: Hi did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

> -bash: grunt: command not found

The above line tells grunt is not installed in your system.

You can install grunt using `sudo npm install grunt -g`

Before this, you have install npm and nodejs in your system, this link 
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-mac will be helpful.

Comment: i forgot to include the part where i install grunt and nothing happens. i do the above you mention. and it gives me this path 'code'/Users/<file path>/.node/bin/grunt -> /Users/<file path>/.node/lib/node_modules/grunt/bin/grunt
when i run grunt in terminal it says command not found

Comment: Hi did you figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use [NVM - Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install and manage your node.js version on MacOS.

And then install Node.js with NVM, e.g.:

```
$ nvm install v6
```

After you successfully installed NVM and Node.js, then install Grunt as global module.

```
$ npm install -g grunt
```

Comment: i may go ahead and try this. What are the benefits of going this way. Why do you suggest this vs. me trying to fix it the way im approaching it? Do I have to uninstall everything ?